# Tomcat Session clustering is not working between two machines instances

Tags: tomcat6, cluster-computing

I have setup 3 instances of tomcat. two are on the same machine, where as another one is on second machine. 
2 tomcat instances ( which are on the same machine ) do share the sessions, but the 3rd instance is not able to share the session with any one.

Please provide some pointer(s). I have already increased the ttl to 255.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a connection issue so that the servers cannot communicate with each other. Have you verified that the required network ports are open between the machines? They are listed in [the official Tomcat clustering documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/cluster-howto.html#For_the_impatient).

Comment: thanks for the reply Axel. 
Third tomcat was not able to share the session as that was not on the same subnet as of other tomcat instances. To make it share the session across the subnet, one need to do some changes with router config etc. ( I didn't tried that, as I could live with that )